# Перестали работать кнопки сохранения в панели управления Joomla 2.5.28

Tags: joomla

Началось недавно, с чем связано - непонятно. Перенос на другой хостинг не делалася.
При нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить", "Сохранить и закрыть" и т.д., в консоли появляется ошибка: [image: скриншот]

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isValid' of undefined
>       at Object.Joomla.submitbutton (index.php?option=com_modules&view=module&layout=edit&id=217:37)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (index.php?option=com_modules&view=module&layout=edit&id=217:258)

Вот тут есть советы, как исправить проблему с неработающими кнопками сохранения [ссылка](https://sitedelkin.ru/zapisnaya-knizhka-vebmastera-reshenie-i-ustranenie-problem/359-ne-rabotayut-knopki-sokhranit-zakryt.html)

В файле administrator/components/com_modules/views/module/tmpl/edit.php замена id="Module-form" на id="adminForm" не помогает.

Смена версии php на хостинге не помогает. Там их на выбор несколько с 5.2 по 7.2, но сайт работает только с версиями 5.3 и 5.4, и при выборе той или другой проблема не исчезает.

Смена шаблона панели управления не помогает.

Замена всей папки administrator папкой из дистрибутива не помогает (по FTP с заменой файлов).

Вот содержимое файла administrator/components/com_modules/views/module/tmpl/edit.php : https://jsfiddle.net/9tb7m5su/

```
$hasContent = empty($this->item->module) || $this->item->module == 'custom' |    | $this->item->module == 'mod_custom';

$script = "Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
    {
if (task == 'module.cancel' || 
document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('module-form'))) {";
if ($hasContent) {
    $script .= $this->form->getField('content')->save();
}
$script .= "    Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('module-form'));
            if (self != top) {
                window.top.setTimeout('window.parent.SqueezeBox.close()', 1000);
            }
        } else {
            alert('".$this->escape(JText::_('JGLOBAL_VALIDATION_FORM_FAILED'))."');
        }
}";

JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration($script);
?>
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php? 
   option=com_modules&layout=edit&id='.(int) $this->item->id); ?>" method="post" 
name="adminForm" id="module-form" class="form-validate">
    <div class="width-60 fltlft">
        <fieldset class="adminForm">
```

Answer (score 0):

Инга, вам нужно найти этот файл:

`www.tvoi_domen.ru/media/system/js/validate.js`

добавьте в конец этого файла следующую строку:

`document.formvalidator = new JFormValidator;`

Затем откройте этот файл в браузере, зайдя в `www.tvoi_domen.ru/media/system/js/validate.js` и обновите его несколько раз (ctrl + F5). Теперь выйдите из системы и войдите в панель управления Joomla. 
Все должно работать.